# Gradle logging level for specific package

Tags: logging, gradle, slf4j

How can I specify logging level for certain java / groovy package?
For example, in *log4j* it is done like:

```
log4j.logger.com.foo.package=WARN
```

Because invoking `gradle --debug` produces too much output.